# Timeout updating DB2 table

Tags: java, sql, db2

I am doing an update to a DB2 table like this (java code):

```
// Some code  ripped out for brevity...
sql.append("UPDATE " + TABLE_THREADS + " ");
sql.append("SET STATUS = ? ");
sql.append("WHERE ID = ?");

conn = getConn();
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
int idx1 = 0;
pstmt.setInt(++idx1, status);
pstmt.setInt(++idx1, id);
int rowsUpdated = pstmt.executeUpdate();
return rowsUpdated;
```

After a long while, I get a rollback and an error message:

`UNSUCCESSFUL EXECUTION CAUSED BY DEADLOCK OR TIMEOUT. REASON CODE 00C9008E, TYPE OF RESOURCE 00000302, AND RESOURCE NAME SOME.THING.X'000002'. SQLCODE=-913, SQLSTATE=57033, DRIVER=3.57.82`

The [documentation for error -913](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes/src/tpc/n913.htm) says this REASON CODE means it is a timeout.  The resource type, 00000302 is a table space page, and I do not recognize the resource name at all.

When I run the SQL by itself, it works fine:

```
UPDATE MY.THREADS
SET STATUS = 1
WHERE ID = 156
```

I can `SELECT` and see the status has been updated.  (Although when I run this SQL during the long wait period before the timeout, I have the same issue.  It takes forever and I just cancel it).

There are several things happening in the transaction and I don't see any other updates to this table or record.  There are create/delete triggers on the table, but no update triggers.  I don't see any selects with cursors, or weird isolation level changes.  I don't see much else in the transaction that would cause this.

**Why am I getting this error?  What else should I look for in the transaction?**

---

#### EDIT:

I stepped through the code from the beginning of the request to where it gets 'stuck'.  It seems as if there are 2 DAO's and both of them are creating a transaction.  I think that might be the problem.

Comment: It looks like the page you are trying to update is locked by another transaction. Are you sure that only one thread at a time is executing this code? It looks like two different transactions are trying to do the same update. The second fails, but the first succeeds, so finally you see the table updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but I found out the problem.  This is a somewhat homemade framework where a DAO keeps track of it's own connection.

```
conn = getConn();
```

This will return the same connection for each DAO method while in an explicit transaction.

While I was stepping through the code, I found out that a method I was calling in my transaction was creating a new transaction, a new DAO, and therefore a new DB connection.  So now I have 2 transactions open and 2 connections.  It's easy to see at this point, that I am in fact deadlocking myself.

This caught me a little by surprise since the previous app I worked on allowed nested transactions.  (Using the same DB connection for both transactions)

Comment: You should definitely accept your own answer then! There is no problem solving your own question.

Answer (score 1):

So SQL connections will timeout, you will need to specify to the connection that you want to "test" the connection before executing a query so that it can then reconnect if it's not still open.

I only have code for the apache commons DBCP and pooling, but here is what I do with my own connections.  The important lines are `connectionPool.setTestOnBorrow(true);` and specifying the validation query `factory.setValidationQuery("select 1");`

```
GenericObjectPool connectionPool = new GenericObjectPool(null);
...
connectionPool.setTestOnBorrow(true); // test the connection before its made
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(connectURI,username, password);

final String validationQuery = null;
KeyedObjectPoolFactory statementPool = new GenericKeyedObjectPoolFactory(null);
PoolableConnectionFactory factory = new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory, connectionPool,
        statementPool, validationQuery, defaultReadOnly, defaultAutoCommit);

factory.setValidationQuery("select 1");    // validate the connection with this statement
```

Comment: I don't think the connection is timing out, I think it is this statement itself.  It is an active connection since I am using it for other select and update statements in the transaction.

Comment: If that's the case, then are there any triggers or foreign key constraints on this table?

Comment: `ID` is defined as a unique index and a primary key.  There are foreign keys on other columns of the table, but not `ID` or `STATUS` which are the only fields involved in the update.  Thanks for the ideas.  Keep them coming  :-)

Comment: Do a describe on the query.  For something that simple it should say the number of rows affected is 1. `desc UPDATE threads_table SET STATUS 1 WHERE ID = 156`

Comment: @Jess are you sure that nobody has a lock on the record?  Do you have it open yourself perhaps?

Comment: Hi @WarrenT, I am in the development system and I am the only one in the database.  This is a web application, so there can be many threads, but there is only one in this case.  If I had it open myself, how would I check that?  Thanks.

Comment: @Jess If I have a table open in one window, it can hold a lock that might prevent an update in another window.  If by some chance you are using DB2 for i, then you could check for locks with the DSPOBJLCK command (and perhaps F6), but on DB2 LUW or z/OS someone else would have to answer that.